# "List" as an unqualified data structure

Tags: c, list, data-structures

When someone says "List" and provides a basic interface without any specifics of the internals, such as:

```
bool   init  (      List *plist)
bool   free  (      List *plist)
size_t size  (const List *plist)
bool   insert(      List *plist, const Item *pitem)
bool   delete(      List *plist, int idx);
```

What is the implementation usually? That is, does it usually mean a "Singly-Linked List", a "Doubly-Linked List", a "Dynamic Array", or any of the above? Basically, is **List** a general term that can mean many variations of a data structure, or does it usually suggest a specific implementation, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: in `GLib`, they call their double-linked lists `GList` and their single linked lists `GSList`. Arrays are called `GArray`, etc, etc. Check out their [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.66/glib-data-types.html). I believe the best way is to just focus on the provided interface and documentation provided, much like you would do with any other language. Your interface may very well be a set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of an Abstract Data Type (ADT) is to focus on how you use the datatype, not on how it is implemented. The interface of the ADT should reflect the operations required to be efficient in the expected use cases.

Having said that, I'd expect the implementation of this particular ADT to be a dynamic array, possibly with a hash index. But that has nothing to do with the name of the datatype.

`List` doesn't say much, and what it does say (in my opinion, that elements are in some specific order) is not reflected in the interface. In fact I'm not at all sure what the point of that interface is. I see how you put things into the collection. But how do you retrieve them?

Anyway, there is no Ultimate Authority of Container Names. So you're as free as Humpty Dumpty to use words to mean what you want them to mean. It's not a coincidence that the work I allude to was written by a mathematician.